# retrieve file from webform using fileUpload restlet

Tags: java, restlet

i want to retrieve a file sending by method post from a webform, i use this code :

```
@Post
public Representation accept(Representation entity) throws FileUploadException, IOException {
    Representation result = null;
    if (entity != null
            && MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.equals(entity.getMediaType(),
                    true)) {
        // 1/ Create a factory for disk-based file items
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(1000240);

        // 2/ Create a new file upload handler based on the Restlet
        // FileUpload extension that will parse Restlet requests and
        // generates FileItems.
        RestletFileUpload upload = new RestletFileUpload(factory);

        // 3/ Request is parsed by the handler which generates a
        // list of FileItems
     //System.out.println(entity.getSize()); 

        FileItemIterator fileIt = upload.getItemIterator(entity);

        // Process only the uploaded item called "fileToUpload"
        // and return back
        boolean found = false;
        while (fileIt.hasNext() && !found) {
            FileItemStream fi = fileIt.next();

            if (fi.getFieldName().equals("fileToUpload")) {
                // For the matter of sample code, it filters the multo
                // part form according to the field name.
                found = true;
                // consume the stream immediately, otherwise the stream
                // will be closed.
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("media type: ");
                sb.append(fi.getContentType()).append("\n");
                sb.append("file name : ");
                sb.append(fi.getName()).append("\n");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fi.openStream()));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                sb.append("\n");
                result = new StringRepresentation(sb.toString(),
                        MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            }
        }

    } else {
        // POST request with no entity.
        setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_BAD_REQUEST);
    }


   return result;
}
```

when i send the request :

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8023
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=------FormBoundary14c70e575bf
Content-Length: 28223

------FormBoundary14c70e575bf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileToUpload"; filename="fileToUpload"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[message-part-body; type:application/octet-stream, size:28037 bytes]
------FormBoundary14c70e575bf--
```

the problem is in the line when i want to build the iterator :

```
FileItemIterator fileIt = upload.getItemIterator(entity);

 mars 31, 2015 7:33:49 PM org.restlet.resource.UniformResource doCatch
AVERTISSEMENT: Exception or error caught in resource
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:593)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:617)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:634)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:1023)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:1003)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:310)
    at org.restlet.ext.fileupload.RestletFileUpload.getItemIterator(RestletFileUpload.java:97)
    at fileupload.FileUploadServerResource.accept(FileUploadServerResource.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:449)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.post(ServerResource.java:1114)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:533)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doNegotiatedHandle(ServerResource.java:590)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doConditionalHandle(ServerResource.java:302)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.handle(ServerResource.java:849)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.handle(Finder.java:513)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:500)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:740)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:155)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.engine.ChainHelper.handle(ChainHelper.java:114)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.ApplicationHelper.handle(ApplicationHelper.java:75)
    at org.restlet.Application.handle(Application.java:391)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:500)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:740)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:500)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:740)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:155)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
    at org.restlet.engine.ChainHelper.handle(ChainHelper.java:114)
    at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:391)
    at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:491)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handle(BaseServerHelper.java:161)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleInbound(BaseServerHelper.java:170)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextInbound(BaseHelper.java:421)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.readMessages(Connection.java:698)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Controller$2.run(Controller.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to add the jar file for Apache Commons IO library within the classpath of your application. That said, you should use Maven to configure and resolve your dependencies since it will handle this for you.

Here is a sample content to configure upload support within Restlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>restlet-upload-sample</artifactId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging> <!-- or war -->
    <version>1.0.0-snapshot</version>

    <properties>
        <restlet-version>2.3.1</restlet-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId> <!-- or org.restlet.jee, ... -->
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-restlet</id>
            <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.restlet.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry